# Load page with large external data while notifying user of progress

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

This is on Asp.Net MVC(>4)
I have an input page where user inputs a list of items (via textboxes).
Once that form is posted, every list item takes about 1-5 seconds to process.
While the request is being processed, I want to show user a loading hint, and once its processed I want to show user of result data for that item and show loading hint if more items are present.
One way is to store the list on client side, show loading hint if there are items to process, and for every list item, call a server method to load the data.
But I want to know if there is a way to post all the data to server at once and do stuff from server-side. Without using SignalR or similar.

Comment: You seem to be aware of, but exclude, the only two viable solutions. I'm not really sure what you're looking for here but I don't think that there's a 3rd approach.

Comment: You could submit all the data at once and have a timer inquiring the server on the progress but that obviously is not a very smart approach.

Comment: Just put a dummy progress indicator on the page to keep the user entertained.